# What real world items do ShippingAssignment objects correspond to

Tags: shipping, class

I've been looking at the class `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignment` and I have absolutely no idea what it represents.

The `OrderInterface` has a shippingAssignments attribute set through extension attributes. `shippingAssignments` is an array of `shippingAssignment` objects, which contain shipping objects and an items array.

When you ship an order in multiple shipments, its still has a single `shippingAssignment` in its `shippingAssignments` attribute. If you create an order with multishipping, it shows up as two unique orders, each with a single `shippingAssignment` each.

Basically, I have no idea how to interpret the `shippingAssignment` class and to know when the `shippingAssignments` attribute might ever have more than a single `shippingAssignment` object in it.